# How to set up a load balancer

Tags: node.js, tcp, load-balancing

I have two servers where multiple tcp services are running on both servers the services are identical.

example :

10.20.30.40:2204
10:20.30.41:2204

has same service I need a load balancer for this such that user will try to connect to

loadbalancerurl.com:2204 and he should be directed to any of the two servers.

I am unable to use load balancers like ngnix cause it needs me to specify ports and i can't specify ports as the backend ports are dynamic I want same port should be carried forward that was used in request

Comment: If ports are dynamic, then this means there is some process, a manager (like for example kubernetes), that governs those ports and assigns them in this or that way. And therefore this manager, this software has to give you ability to setup/integrate a load balancer. Otherwise the only option you have is to get rid of the manager and deploy those servers with static ports. If you can't do that then you are screwed. Btw, it is very unusual for a server to have dynamic port. Why would you even do that?

Comment: it's like if person installs a software in his machine then the port will listen and it will be removed if he uninstalls that's why i can't mention in ngnix conf

Comment: That doesn't explain why the port cannot be fixed. Either way, if it is something configurable by user, then he has to provide this information to you in some way.